# Time Zone difference in browsers

Tags: javascript, datetime, cross-browser, timezone

I am retrieving a DateTime field from the database via JSON in the following string syntax:

```
2015-12-17T12:00:00
```

I convert it to a date as below:

```
<script>
   var myDate = new Date("2015-12-17T12:00:00");
   document.write(myDate);
</script>
```

The problem is that Safari and Chrome assume this to be UTC time (which is the way I want it) and IE assumes this to be local time.

Sample output from Chrome/Safari:

```
Thu Dec 17 2015 17:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Sample output from IE Edge/11/10

```
Thu Dec 17 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

See Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tQAqmdWAuL8k0vGKPLCx?p=preview

How can I correct this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the solution. Add a "Z" at the end of the date:

```
015-12-17T12:00:00Z
```

Comment: That is correct, though the best solution would be to have the back-end include the Z during serialization.  Most serializers will do this when configured properly.  If you give some details about the back-end, I may be able to offer advice on how to do it correctly.

Comment: We're using ASP.Net Web API to return C# objects. Objects are populated from the database using Dapper.

Comment: As you load your `DateTime` objects from the database, they will probably have their `.Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` by default.  If they are actually in terms of UTC, then use `DateTime.SpecifyKind` to set `DateTimeKind.Utc` immediately on load.  You can either do this manually each time, or set up a `TypeHandler` in dapper to do it for you.  Alternatively, store a `datetimeoffset` in SQL and use a `DateTimeOffset` type in .NET (with offset set to `+00:00` for UTC).  Either way, once done, the serialization in JSON.net will correctly add the `Z` or the offset.

Comment: Many thanks. The simplest solution that works for me now is `new Date(usr.LastAccess+'Z')` . I'll revisit this later and get something done on the back-end (which is another story with another team altogether!)

Comment: You should also consider [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  You could use `moment.utc(usr.lastAccess)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>
   var myDate = new Date("2015-12-17T12:00:00").toUTCString();
   document.write(myDate);
</script>
```

Comment: @navigator I am not able to vote up but yes your solution will work. :) (Y)

Comment: You are converting back to a string. I cannot do that as I need to perform further operations on the datetime variable.

Comment: yes that was in my mind but I found that solution which is given by you after posting mine. No problem your solution is better one in your case.

Comment: This is not a good solution, as it will interpret the time in the same inconsistent manner as mentioned in the original question.  Also, the behavior has changed between ES5 and ES6, so implementations will vary.

Comment: Thanx @MattJohnson your comment will help others not to do this one :)

Comment: I recommend deleting this answer.  Eventually someone will come along and downvote it otherwise.

Comment: Down vote doesn't matter for me. Main thing is to be aware of both right and wrong both ways so we'll have an efficient answer. If you can so do down vote it. I am not able to do that.